# How to remove TimeOfDay text once you've picked a time from timePicker in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using the timePicker in Flutter.

Once I have picked the time from the popup dialog it displays the picked time but it doesn't display only the time eg: `12:45`, it also shows `TimeOfDay eg: TimeOfDay(12:45)`.

How do I get rid of the TimeOfDay text?

```
//Declaration example
TimeOfDay _time = new TimeOfDay.now();
```

```
//Time picker example code
Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: _time);`

    if (picked != null && picked != _time) {
      print('${_time.toString()}');
      setState(() {
        _time = picked;
      });
    }
  }
```

```
//Display example
Text(
   '${_time.toString()}',
),
```

I would like the time to look like: `12:45` and not:`TimeOfDay(12:45)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will print in the required format.

```
Text(
   _time.format(context),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

String interpolation of hour and minute will work:

```dart
"${_time.hour}:${_time.minute}"
```